# define a variable in a query (?)

Tags: php, variables

I have to define two variables:

```
<?php 
$path =  'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/root/images/folderX/'; 
$files = scandir('images/folderX/'); 
?>
```

In the place of 'folderX' I should use a dynamic value, which comes from a query, like

```
<?php echo $row_rsQuery["item_name"];?>
```

How can it be done?

I'm not too familiar with php, and I will perhaps never learn it (..too old..), but I solve most of my problems with Dreamweaver, however the above problem is beyond its (and my) capabilities...

Comment: You'd do it the same way you build the `$path` variable: `scandir('images/'.$row_rsQuery["item_name"].'/')`. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$path =  'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/root/images/'.$row_rsQuery["item_name"].'/';   
$files = scandir('images/'.$row_rsQuery["item_name"].'/');
```

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation (appending one string to another) is done via the `.` operator:

```
$files = scandir('images/'.$row_rsQuery["item_name"]);
```